# Option for Integrating Google Webmaster into Analytics is Missing

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I have been asked to integrate Google Webmaster with Google Analytics. I have been looking up tutorials but to no avail.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006?hl=en

The above says to "On the Webmaster Tools home page, click Manage site next to the site you want, and then click Google Analytics property."

I, however, do not see this option. The only option is delete. Other turorials such as this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0KDVenYgCA

Use an older version of Analytics.

So how can I achieve what is desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you were added as a "restricted" or "full" user and don't have the ability to link to a Analytics account.  [Only "owner" level users in GWT have permissions to link to an Analytics account](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999?hl=en).

When I am a site owner, I have the option in the manage dropdown to link to analytics as well as an option to manage other users:

[image: Google Webmaster Tools Manage site drop down menu]

Google has instructions for [adding an owner to a site in Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2454036).   Somebody with owner permissions would have to add you as such.  Presumably you could also use file, meta tag, or DNS record verification to become a site owner.